# How to design my website so that it has proper functionality for mobile phones?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

Im new to web designing, and ive created this site. i want the navbar to become a clickable dropdown menu and go to the top if the user is opening the site on mobile. Ive added a picture.if you can please explain in detail. Thanks in advance.
[Picture of my table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/858On.png)

The navbar element is named as navbar and is part of the tmpmainpage template

```
<body onload(setData)>
    
    <bbl-mainpage id="MainPage" opts="Inventory,Ledger,Graph,Settings" col="navbar,content">
    </bbl-mainpage>

    <template id="tmpMainPage">
        <style>
        
            * {
                height: 100%;
                width: 100%;

            }
            
            :host .logo {
                /* top: 10px; */
                width: 95%;
                height: 15%;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                display: flex;
                position: absolute;
            }

            :host .navbar {
                height: 100%;
                width: 10vw;
                position: fixed;
                z-index: 1;
                top: 0;
                left: 0;
                background: #2f4f4f;
                overflow: none;
                padding-top: 20px;
                display: block;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                text-align: center;
                flex-flow: column;

            }

            :host .navbar .options {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: repeat(5, .5fr);
                height: 200px;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                left: 0;
                bottom: 30%;
                color: white;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
                float: left;

            }

            :host .navbar .logout {
                display: grid;
                grid-template-rows: repeat(5, .5fr);
                height: 100px;
                width: 100%;
                position: absolute;
                z-index: 1;
                left: 0;
                top: 70%;
                color: white;
                margin: 0 auto;
                padding: 15px 0 5px 0;
                float: left;
            }

            :host a {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
            }

            :host .navbar a:hover {
                background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
            }

            .activated,
            :host .navbar a:active {
                background-color: #2f6f6f;
            }

            .deactived {
                background-color: rgba(0, 97, 50, 1);
            }

            :host .mainDiv .content {
                position: fixed;
                width: 90vw;
                float: right;
                top: 0;
                bottom: 0;
                right: 0;
            }

          
            .settings :host .mainDiv {
                width: 100vw;
                height: 100vh;
            }
        </style>
        <div class="mainDiv">
            <div class="navbar">
                <div class="options"></div>
                <div class="logout">
                    <a href="logout.php" style="color: white;">Log Out</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="content">
                
            </div>
        </div>
    </template>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a media query ('@media') to know when a mobile device is accessing your website, and apply the proper CSS inside of it when it happens.

```
@media only screen and (max-width:640px) {

     <!-- all your css for a top dropdown navbar here -->

}
```

You can read into it more here: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_mediaquery.asp

Comment: Yes ive tried it but how do i convert it into an div that is a clickable dropdown.

Comment: I think it would be best if you transform your current div into a clickable dropdown using CSS inside the media query. For example, changing the position of the navigation bar to the top by using the top and left offsets to move it to the top when on a mobile device. Here is a reference for making mobile navigation menus: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_mobile_navbar.asp

Answer (score 0):

One of the many tools made to build a fully responsive site could be a combination of things. One thing that's important to note is to have a general understanding.

So having that in mind, I would suggest that you have a look at [CSS Media Queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries).
Then when you gain an understanding, you can move on to powerful grid systems and CSS Frameworks.

Short Example of Media Queries:

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body {
    background-color: lightblue;
  }
}
```

The style of the above example will only execute once the screen width hits 600px.

Another thing to keep in mind when working with responsive design is that mobile devices are constantly in development, and the quality is becoming better and better, meaning that [Retina Display](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/retina-display-media-query/) is also something to consider when optimizing your webpage for multiple devices.

[Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/) is a very powerful CSS-kit that will allow you to build fully responsive websites.

[Bootstrap](https://getbootstrap.com/) is a very popular CSS Framework that also utilizes Flexbox in its many powerful classes. You can find out much more about Bootstrap by [reading the documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/getting-started/introduction/).

Comment: Thank you! ill have a look into bootstrap seems interesting.